# Python thread class instance change a variable for all instances

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I'm new to python threads and I can't find any answers for that. If it is a duplicate question sorry for that.
I have a thread class like this:

```
class Ant(Thread):
    def __init__(self, start_item, possible_items, backpack_limit, pheromone_map, alpha, beta, eta):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start_item = start_item
        self.item = start_item
        self.possible_items = possible_items
        self.selected_items = []
        self.backpack_limit = backpack_limit
        self.weight_sum = 0
        self.backpack_value = 0
        self.pheromone_map = pheromone_map
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta
        self.eta = eta  # (weight/value)

        # append start location to route, before doing random walk
        self.add_backpack(start_item)
        self.tour_complete = False

    def run(self):
        while self.possible_items and self.is_remaining_space_feasible():
            next_item = self.pick_item()
            self.item = next_item
            self.add_backpack(next_item)
        self.tour_complete = True

    def add_backpack(self, next_item):
        self.update_items(next_item)
        self.update_backpack(next_item)

    def update_items(self, next_item):
        self.selected_items.append(next_item)
        self.possible_items.remove(next_item)

    def update_backpack(self, next_item):
        self.weight_sum += next_item.get_weight()
        self.backpack_value += next_item.get_value()
```

and I create bunch of instances in another class like this:
`ants = [Ant(self.items[random.randint(0, len(self.items) - 1)], self.items, self.backpack_limit, self.pheromone_matrix, self.alpha, self.beta, self.eta) for _ in range(self.ant_count)]`

As you can see when I create an ant instance it's called add_backpack function and at some point this piece of code work `self.possible_items.remove(next_item)` and the program finished the initialization step and create the next instance. But for the next instance `possible_items` already removed the item and this caused **list.remove(x): x not in list** error. I tried deep copying but it's doesn't work.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but isn’t `Thread.__init...` just `super().__init...` ? In any case, we’re going to need all the code and data necessary to reproduce this. Please see: [mcve].

Comment: @AMC Not necessarily, though you need to construct a class using multiple inheritance to demonstrate the difference.

Comment: What is `self.items` when you are creating all these instances of `Ant`? They all appear to be sharing the same list.

Comment: @chepner ```self.items``` is a list of custom item class it only contains 3 variables. Like I said I tried deep copying ```self.items``` like ```copy.deepcopy(self.items)``` each time when I create an ant instance but it didn't work.

Comment: I did not quite get the entire question, but based on the question title, if you want to change a variable from one instance of thread class to affect the same variable in other instances, then you can use static class variable. Let me know if I understood your question correctly, I'll convert it to answer with example code.